# Laravel no reconoce los paramteros de mi ruta

Tags: laravel

> Buenas tengo la siguiente ruta.

```
Route::resource('historial_consultas', HistConsultaController::class);

Los parametros que la ruta espera son los siguientes.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de usar mi mis controladores show, edit y delete no me reconoce el parametro y se lo especifique en la ruta de esta manera.

```
  <a href="{{route('historial_consultas.destroy',['historial_consulta'=>$historial_consulta])}}">Delete</a>
```

Me esta siendo incomodo resolver este error si alguien me puede
ayudar estaria agradecido. POSDT: Hice el mismo ejemplo en otro
proyecto y me funciona pero en este no.

Comment: ¿Y si pruebas con?: **`'historial_consulta'=>$historial_consulta->id`**

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que esos métodos son POST, me parece que si usas la URL ejecuta por defecto el metodo GET.

Si estas seguro de que el código no es el problema, ya que te funciona en otro proyecto, puedes usar:
`php artisan route:clear`

Esto hará que las rutas se refresquen y eliminen la caché de estas. Tuve un problema similar y lo solucioné así.

Answer (score 0):

Cual es el nombre del atributo dentro del controlador? Laravel irá a buscar el parametro de la URL que coincida con el atributo del método.

por ejemplo:

si en tu controlador el método show está esperando un id

```
public function show($id) ...
```

Entonces debes de llamar al parámetro de la ruta de la misma manera.

Según tu ejemplo el método show debería de ser

```
public function show($historial_consulta)
```

Básicamente no lo reconoce porque no lo encuentra.